# MP3 Search results to audio player

Tags: php, html

I operate a website that searches soundcloud for music results and I'm trying to have an audio player play the search results, however I'm having a little trouble.

For each search result I use this `{$mp3_search[mp3].mp3_url}` which is the direct link to the song.  But just putting that line of code into a standard open source audio player does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your source code so that we can help you.

Comment: its too long to post what exactly do you need?

Comment: We need the file where {$mp3_search[mp3].mp3_url} is set, and the file where {$mp3_search[mp3].mp3_url} is used.

Comment: Is this what you needed?

Comment: You don't appear to have posted any source code for us.

Comment: I actually figured it out, problem was i was not adding my client id and was getting a 401- unauthorized error from soundcloud thanks tho :)

Comment: OK then. I'll close/get someone to close the question now.

Comment: Somebody close this question please, I've not got enough rep.

Comment: Hey connor just wondering, do you have any experience with soundmanager 2? Just simply getting it to work